# OpenMP v4.0 GOMP_task()

Tags: task, openmp

I'm trying to implement my own version of the libgomb library. Now I'm implementing the GOMP_task() function but there are somo parameters that I don´t understand.

```
void
GOMP_task (void (*fn) (void *), void *data, void (*cpyfn) (void *, void *),
       long arg_size, long arg_align, bool if_clause, unsigned flags,
       void **depend)
```

I have problems with this parameters

```
unsigned flags
void **depend
```

When I compile this code with my own libgomp library

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{ 


    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,3) 
    for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        #pragma omp task shared(result) depend(in:result) depend(out:result)
        {
            result++;}
        #pragma omp task depend(in:result) depend(out:result)
            result++;
 }

 #pragma omp taskwait
 printf("result = %ld\n", result);
 }
```

I print those two parameters and flags is always 8 and depend is always the same value even if the differents tasks depens of differents variables.

There is any document with information about that? Because I haven't found anything.

Or does anybody knows about that function?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code of libgomp? The OpenMP lowering code in GCC will definitely be of help too.

Comment: Looking at the GOMP source is not an option if the OP wants to use a different license.

Comment: @Jeff Looking at the source code is always an option. Plagiarizing it, on the other hand, is probably not.

Comment: @ManuelM You seem to not understand the issues here. May I recommend you read up on copyleft, the legal ramifications of the GPL and why companies "Chinese Wall" or "clean room" code?

Comment: @Daniel Can I ask why you are implementing your own version of OpenMP? I too am trying to understand what OpenMP does behind the scenes when it creates a task.